# If $(\varphi_n)$ is uniformly equicontinuous and $0\le f_n\le-3\ln\varphi_n$, show that $(f_n)$ is equicontinuous at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $(\varphi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq C(\mathbb R^d)$ be uniformly equicontinuous with $\varphi_n(0)=1$ and $\varphi_n>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq C(\mathbb R^d)$ with $$0\le f_n\le-3\ln\varphi_n\tag1\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N.$$

> How can we show that
>
> 1. $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\sup_{\overline B_1(0)}f_n<\infty$; and
> 2. $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is equicontinuous at $0$?

Regarding 1.: Since $(\varphi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is uniformly equicontinuous, there is a $\delta>0$ with $$\forall n\in\mathbb N:\forall x\in B_\delta(0):\varphi_n(x)>\frac12\tag2.$$ Now we somehow need to use $(1)$ ...

Regarding 2.: Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $(\varphi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is equicontinuous at $0$ and $\varphi_n(0)=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, there is a $\delta>0$ with $$\forall n\in\mathbb N:\forall x\in B_\delta(0):|\varphi_n(x)-1|<\varepsilon\tag3.$$ How can we use this (and probably $(1)$) to show the claim?

Comment: The first statement is false as written: Consider $\varphi_n:=\max\{ 1/2- |x|, e^{-n/3}\}$, then (1) for $|x|>1/2$ and $n$ large enough is simply saying $0\leq f_n\leq n$ which is not enough to conclude. Part 2 is an application of the squeeze theorem, noting that $\varphi_n\leq 1$ for every $n$.

Comment: @Jose27 Thank you for your comment. The actual $\varphi_n$ that I've got in mind is of the form $\varphi_n=e^{\varphi_{\mu_n}-\mu_n(\mathbb R^d)}$, where $\varphi_{\mu_n}$ is the characteristic function of a finite measure $\mu_n(\mathbb R^d)$. Does this special choice have additional properties which are crucial for (1.)?

Comment: @Jose27 BTW the claim(s) can be found in the proof of [Lemma 5.3.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWKes.png) of "Probability in Banach Spaces--stable and Infinitely Divisible Distributions" by Werner Linde.

Comment: In that case (1) becomes $$0\leq f_n\leq 3(\mu_n(\mathbb{R}^d)-\varphi_n)=3(\varphi_n(0)-\varphi_n),$$so for example if you know that $\mu_n(\mathbb{R}^d)\leq C$ for some constant $C$ and all $n$ then the result follows. Otherwise I think we need more information as to what $e(\lambda_n)$ being r.s.c. means...